# Sed failing to replace, UTF-8 encoding

Tags: linux, bash, utf-8, sed, pattern-matching

I am trying to do some file content transformations. I am operating in a Linux with text encoding:

```
echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
```

I am accessing from a Putty terminal with the following configuration under Window -> Translation -> Remote character set -> UTF-8

I have the following log file that I want to do transformations on:

```
cat test.log | head
```

This is what I see in the terminal/if I edit the file with nano/if I copy and paste the terminal content into notepad in Windows (notice three dashes after the first IP):

```
10.0.2.4 - - - Cookie= -  [11/Jun/2014:12:51:48 +0000]
"GET /hub/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20140429 Firefox/24.0 Iceweasel/24.5.0" "1.1.1.1"
```

This is what I see if I copy/paste the content into here/wordpad in Windows (notice only one dash after the first IP):

```
10.0.2.4 ­ - ­ Cookie= -  [11/Jun/2014:12:51:48 +0000]
"GET /hub/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20140429 Firefox/24.0 Iceweasel/24.5.0" "1.1.1.1"
```

I try to apply the following transformation with sed:

```
cat test.log | sed "s,- - - Cookie=,-,g"
```

The transformation doesn't do anything I get the same result as before (different depending on where I am viewing/copy-pasting).

If I select with the mouse and copy from the contents of the file on the terminal the pattern "- - - Cookie=" and paste it on the terminal on the sed command then it does replace well.

Obtaining this result both on the terminal and copy-pasting it elsewhere:

```
10.0.2.4 - -  [11/Jun/2014:12:51:48 +0000]
    "GET /hub/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20140429 Firefox/24.0 Iceweasel/24.5.0" "1.1.1.1"
```

So I created a script selecting with the mouse and copy-pasting from the contents of the file on the terminal the dash "-" and replacing it with a dash typed "by hand":

```
cat test.log | sed "s,-,-,g" > test1.log
```

(First dash is copy-pasted from the contents of the file, second is written manually).

However, I still can't get the sed transformation on the file test1.log to work properly:

```
cat test.log | sed "s,- - - Cookie=,-,g"
```

Produces the same result as initially...

The encoding of the file is UTF-8:

```
file -bi test.log
text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: Run the relevant lines through `hexdump`, play a bit with the `-b`, `-c` and `-d` options.

Comment: Thanks lxg, I used hexdump to get to the answer...

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing `- - - Cookie=` with `-` of course you get `- -`, this is what you are telling it to do. if you want to keep the `Cookie=` part you need to add it to the replacement text. try:

```
cat test.log | sed 's/- - - Cookie=/- Cookie=/g'
```

Notes: Using simple quotes with `sed` is better than double quotes, you can't forget to unescape `$`-s and `\`-s that are still active inside double quotes. Also, while you can use any separator character with `sed`, `/` is the preferred one, and it looks a lot better than `,`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Just by performing a cat of the file I get different results depending on where I am viewing/copy-pasting.

If I type the sed command manually it does not replace "- - - Cookie=" with "-". I only get this result by selecting with the mouse and copying from the cat contents the pattern "- - - Cookie=" then pasting it into the sed command...

Besides, I can't do this on batch as explained even if I try replacing the "-" copying from the cat file terminal and pasting it in sed with a normal dash...

Comment: It works for me, what you've posted is plain ASCII, there are no UTF-8 sequences in it. Perhaps in the original text you have some invisible UTF-8 characters that you don't see in the pattern, but they are there when you Copy+Paste it. Try using a hex editor, to see the actual bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to lxg and Evan Dark. I solved it in this way using hexdump:

```
hexdump -C test1.log
```

Getting this result:

```
00000000  31 30 2e 30 2e 32 2e 34  20 c2 ad 20 2d 20 c2 ad  |10.0.2.4 .. - ..|
00000010  20 43 6f 6f 6b 69 65 3d  20 2d 20 20 5b 31 37 2f  | Cookie= -  [17/|
```

So the 16 sets of 2 hexadecimal numbers on the left represent each character on ASCII on the right. Therefore, I just have to substutite ".." (ASCII) "c2 ad" (hexadecimal) with a dash (-).

I do this by using sed in this way:

```
cat test1.log | sed 's/\xc2\xad/-/g'
```

Obtaining:

```
10.0.2.4 - - - Cookie= -  [11/Jun/2014:12:51:48 +0000]
"GET /hub/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20140429 Firefox/24.0 Iceweasel/24.5.0" "1.1.1.1"
```

Then my previous sed command works flawlessly:

```
cat test1.log | sed 's/\xc2\xad/-/g' | sed "s,- - - Cookie=,-,g"

10.0.2.4 - -  [11/Jun/2014:12:51:48 +0000]
"GET /hub/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20140429 Firefox/24.0 Iceweasel/24.5.0" "1.1.1.1"
```